Did medieval European artists mix pigments or did they frown upon doing so for superstitious reasons?
Wikipedia claims that medieval European artists didn't typically mix colored pigments "due to suspicion of alchemy", but this claim feels odd, so I wanted to reach out to some experts to verify it.
Wikipedia has this to say on the page for Teal:

Green pigments for paints and fabric dyes were difficult to obtain from nature in the past, thus they were rarely employed in clothes or heraldic emblems. While green may have been blended with blue and yellow paints, mixing dissimilar substances was frowned upon due to suspicion of alchemy. Only during the early Renaissance did the superstitious custom fade away, and in the late eighteenth century, the German Swedish scientist Carl Wilhelm Scheele found new copper greens.[20]

(Permalink to this revision of "Teal" in case the page changes.)
This citation 20 is to

"Color teal: Meaning and how to use it in branding". Mojomox. Retrieved 22 June 2021.

Visiting the Mojomox page, we find the following text:

Although a mix between green and blue of equal parts and really a color of its own, teal often gets pulled into the green color family. Historically, green pigments for paints and fabric dyes were hard to extract from nature and therefore weren’t often used in clothing and heraldic arms. While green could have been mixed with pigments from the color blue and the color yellow, there was a deep dislike to mixing different substances due to distrust in alchemy. This medieval precursor of chemistry transformed matter by combining elements seemingly through magic. The superstitious convention vanished only during the early Renaissance and new copper greens were discovered by German Swedish chemist Carl Wilhelm Scheele in the late eighteenth century. [1]
[…]
[1] Clair, Kassia St. The Secret Lives of Color. Penguin Books, 2017.

(Wayback Machine link in case this page changes or goes down.)
Now, I've put a hold on Kassia St. Clair's The Secret Lives of Color from my local library, but I don't have it yet, so I have to look to other sources.  (If I get a copy of that book, it has the answer for me, and this question hasn't been answered yet, I'll self-answer this question!)
Looking online, we can go to the website for the Fitzwilliam Museum in Cambridge instead of a website about branding.  They have information about medieval illuminators where they're described as mixing colors and being praised for it (emphasis mine):

The Illuminators' Palette
Illuminators employed a wide range of colourants, both man-made and naturally available. Organic pigments were derived from various sources, including plants, insects and molluscs. Inorganic ones were produced from minerals, earths and metals, including gold and silver.
Modern perceptions of colour are dominated by hue, but medieval and Renaissance artists and viewers were equally sensitive to its other aspects: texture, luminosity (brilliance) and intensity (saturation). To capture these effects and create a richer palette, illuminators juxtaposed, layered and mixed pigments. They experimented with new materials adopted from the glass, ceramic and textile industries.
Medieval and Renaissance viewers admired both the precious colourants and the craftsmanship that ensured their long-lasting beauty. Exotic rarity, long-distance trade, complex production and colour fastness increased the monetary and symbolic value of pigments. But the skill of the artists who applied them was equally important.

(Wayback Machine link in case this page changes or goes down.)
This certainly makes it sound like mixing colored pigments was a popular medieval activity!
So: Wikipedia via a branding website, or a university museum of arts and antiquities?  Who should I trust? :-)

In those days, color pigments mixed very poorly, and often didn't mix at all. The artists proceeded by successive layers after drying, and played with binders to obtain shades from the same pigment. The medieval Latin words "alchemia"(alchemy) and "chemia"(chemistry) were synonyms until the XVIIth century.
